# audio that can always be paused

Tags: javascript, html, audio, scroll

Say I want to load an audio file onto a webpage. Maybe it autoloads, but the point is, it stays at the top of the window so it can always be paused or played. I know I've seen this but I don't know the code.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp
And when you don't now how to do something maybe try first looking at the docs or some tutorials.

Comment: I looked at that page and it doesn't talk about this. I know how to use the audio tag just not how to anchor the controls to the top or bottom of the window.

Answer (score 1):

And it looks like I was looking for an answer in the wrong place. This isn't about audio controls, it's about div controls. A div can be "fixed" to the bottom or top of a page-

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

I thought this was an html/javascript question, but it's more relative to css.

Comment: I have to remember HTML for the raw material on the website
CSS for structure
Javascript for actions
(Well the audio controls are HTML too but that's an exception.)